# Linux Bash, Test command, why [ 0 -ne 0 ] is false instead of true?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, testing, rhel

When using test command in Linux Bash and numeric comparison between "Zero" equal to "zero" fetches an exit code 0 through echo $?

```
$[ 0 -eq 0 ]
$echo $?
0
```

However, when testing the same with an NOT EQUAL, why my exit code shows false and exit with value 1?

```
$[ 0 -ne 0 ]
$echo $?
1
```

man Test

```
INTEGER1 -ne INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is not equal to INTEGER2
```

Could someone explain the logic behind the **not equal to** when equating with a same integer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about but maybe about `Exits with a
status of 0 (true) or 1 (false)` part from `help test`?

Comment: I don't understand why this is unexpected. `-ne` should return true (0) if the numbers are different from each other, and return false (1) if they're the same (which they are in this case).

Comment: Don't think of it as "true" and "false", but as "success" and "failure".  The `if` keyword does not evaluate a boolean condition; instead it checks the status of a command.  `[ 0 -eq 0 ]` succeeds, but `[ 0 -ne 0 ]` fails.

Comment: Because `0` is ***not, not equal*** to `0`!!

Answer (score 0):

In bash, 0 (which really means no error) means true, non-zero (such as 1) means there was some error, AKA false.

Try this:

```sh
if [ 0 -ne 0 ]
then
  echo The above is not true
else
  echo The above is true
fi
```

Or, in one-liner form:

```sh
if [ 0 -ne 0 ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

Comment: Better not to think of `[` as producing true or false at all; `[` *succeeds* when its condition is true, and *fails* when the condition is false.

Comment: @chepner That is true (no punt intended).

Answer (score 0):

Convention is that an exit code of zero means success and non-zero means error/failure. Consider:

```
$ true
$ echo $?
0
$ false
$ echo $?
1
$ if true; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
ok
$ if false; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
no
$ if [ 0 -ne 0 ]; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
no
```